# Apply dilation rate individually to each dimension with tf.nn.atrous_conv2d?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, convolution

I have a tensor with shape `B x H x W x C` and I like to apply dilation to only `H`. Do you know any way to have this small trick with [`tf.nn.atrous_conv2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/atrous_conv2d)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature in `tf.nn.atrous_conv2d`, but you can use [`tf.layers.conv2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/conv2d) and set `dilation_rate=(2, 1)` to achieve the same effect.